# How to add requestHeader to the generated interface with openapi-generator-maven-plugin

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openapi-generator

I am using `openapi-generator-maven-plugin` to generate the server code for a springboot application.

However I can't figure out a easy way to generate the `@RequestHeader("header")` in the interface.

Here is the plugin configuration:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- RELEASE_VERSION -->
                <version>5.1.0</version>
                <!-- /RELEASE_VERSION -->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/spec/api.yaml</inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                            <apiPackage>my.api</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>my.models</modelPackage>
                            <configOptions>
                                <delegatePattern>false</delegatePattern>
                                <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                                <useTags>true</useTags>
                <useOptional>true</useOptional>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

API spec:

```
    get:
      tags:
        - template
      summary: find template by template name
      description: returns single template
      operationId: getTemplateByName
      parameters:
        - name: bucket
          in: path
          description: location
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
        - name: templateName
          in: path
          description: the name of the template
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        200:
          description: successful operation
          content:
            multipart/mixed:
              schema:
                type: object
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Template'
        400:
          description: Invalid input
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Error'
        404:
          description: template not found
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Error'
```

The generated interface:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "find template by template name", nickname = "getTemplateByName", notes = "returns single template", response = Object.class, tags={ "template", })
    @ApiResponses(value = { 
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "successful operation", response = Object.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Invalid input", response = Error.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "template not found", response = Error.class) })
    @ApiImplicitParams({
    })
    @GetMapping(
        value = "/bu/{bucket}/templates/{templateName}",
        produces = { "multipart/mixed", "application/json" }
    )
    default ResponseEntity<Object> getTemplateByName(@ApiParam(value = "location",required=true) @PathVariable("bucket") String bucket,@ApiParam(value = "the name of the template",required=true) @PathVariable("templateName") String templateName) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);

    }
```

How to add @RequestHeader to the interface? or is there a way it can generate the httprequest in the interface?

Comment: Did you ever found an answer to how to add the accept parameter? I run into the exact same problem.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution? Second answer showed how to add header in config but would it allow to set runtime calculated value for this header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned at [swagger Docs](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/) this can be done using `header` like the following

```yaml
paths:
  /ping:
    get:
      summary: Checks if the server is alive
      parameters:
        - in: header
          name: X-Request-ID
          schema:
            type: string
            format: uuid
          required: true
```

In a similar way, you can define custom response headers. Header parameter can be primitives, arrays and objects. Arrays and objects are serialized using the simple style.

Note: Header parameters named Accept, Content-Type and Authorization are not allowed. To describe these headers, use the corresponding OpenAPI keywords:

Comment: Thanks for the info. What I need is to access the Accept header which I have already defined in the response according to the doc. I think the problem is more about how to use the maven plugin to generate the corresponding method parameters for springboot

Answer (score 0):

I dig up this topic, I used this plugin too, and I added a header for authentication, because I added springboot security
and on version 1.4 we can set headers directly in the plugin

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>integration-test</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <apiDocsUrl>http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs/spring-public</apiDocsUrl>
      <outputFileName>openapi.json</outputFileName>
      <outputDir>target/springdoc/maven-output</outputDir>
      <skip>false</skip>
      <headers>
        <Authorization>Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==</Authorization>
      </headers>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```